# File that is bieng write (downloaded) has not same content as webpage

Tags: java

```
// Create URL object 
        URL url = new 
               URL("http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javaconcurrency/index.html"); 
        BufferedReader readr =  
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); 

        // Enter filename in which you want to download 
        BufferedWriter writer =  
          new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Download.html")); 
          
        // read each line from stream till end 
        String line; 
        while ((line = readr.readLine()) != null) { 
            writer.write(line);
```

Main problem is decoding the output that i read using reader.readline()

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the URL you are loading. What exactly do you mean by "decoding"?

Comment: I want to download webpage using java , so I used FileWrite to write data from inputstream that is return by url.openstream() . data is writed in file now when i open file it is not looking like webpage that I downloaded.

Comment: Depending on the content and HTML code of the webpage, there might be other files missing like images or CSS files. Without them the HTML code you downloaded will look differently when viewed in a browser since all the other files are missing.

Answer (score 1):

The java [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) represents a stream of characters and the [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) converts (wraps) a stream of bytes into a stream of characters. It is imperative for it to use the **correct [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)**.

It is certainly possible to do it by parsing the value of `url.openConnection().getContentType()` (cf. the *"Gather HTTP response information"* section of this [BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/11748454)), but in your case it is **useless**: just read the bytes from the URL and write them to your file, without converting them to `char`s in the middle:

```java
try (final InputStream is = url.openStream();
     final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Download.html");) {
    final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
        os.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
}
```